# Confusion over "respected" in the following sentence

Tags: meaning

I'm confused what this sentence means. Does it mean that many people consider X respected, or that a few people consider X respected?

> not a few people consider respected
>   and X to be an oxymoron

Side question: is this sentence structure convoluted or is it just me?

Comment: That should maybe be changed to be "not a few people consider 'respected and X' to be an oxymoron."  BTW, does X = "feared" (or is there not a particular X)?

Comment: @user7834 The X is actually the name of a person. I didn't think it would appropriate to put the name here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that **many people consider X the opposite of respected**.

*Not a few* means "many".

An *oxymoron* is a witty combination of opposite terms.

And, yes, this sentence is very convoluted; that is probably done ironically and on purpose. It is a figure of speech that is supposed to be mildly entertaining.

Comment: +1 OK, but it is perhaps wishful thinking to attribute to irony that which can be adequately explained by incompetence ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think it may also intended to convey that the author of the sentence may not agree with the statement. Maybe more than 'not a few' consider it, as in, 'many', but the author considers those 'many' to be incorrect in their usage so therefore they highlight this disagreement with the use of 'not a few'.

You could also have the complete opposite interpretation. I.e., they agree with the 'not a few' and are trying to use hyperbole. I.e., "not a few people consider wife-beating to be wrong."

It really depends on the context of use which is really hard to determine with what is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "not a few" in this case means a lot. It is an example of *litotes*, a rhetorical figure involving understatement through negation of the reverse (think about when someone says a thing is "not bad" they actually mean it is good.).

That said, there's something a bit stuffy about the way it's used here.

Comment: It's *bad* litotes.  It's gratuitous and it weighs down any already overburdened sentence.  Even the corrected "many people" begs for a Wiki-esque `[citation needed]`.  How about "The phrase 'respected and X' is an oxymoron" ?

Comment: Almost, but not quite, entirely unlike tea.

Comment: I don't know. Things of this nature are really dependent on the context of use. If the author has been writing in a self deprecating manner or in a manner that is belittling of the subject at hand then it can be interpreted in a multitude of ways depending on what was previously written. Imho modern usage of this is normally done for comedic effect or to highlight interpretive irony.

Comment: @Malvolio: Wow, I wasn't even on your lawn.

Comment: please don't take my comment as any criticism of *you* .  I'm glad to see someone besides me interested in rhetorical forms (my proudest day as a parent was when my daughter pointed out an example of antimetabole on a billboard).  I just thought the original sentence was bad, bad writing.